# Why does the script run 2 times?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to know the holidays of a team. For this, everyone receives by mail a form with 4 questions:
- Mail address
- Name
- Beginning of the leave period
- End of the leave period

Typically, responses are sent in a spreadsheet.
The idea is to fill a calendar shared with the whole team so that everyone knows the periods of leave.
For this, here is the script to link to this worksheet:

```
function AjouteConge() {
  var fichier = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var feuille = fichier.getActiveSheet();
  var Ligne = fichier.getLastRow();
  var RefCellule = "B"+Ligne+":E"+Ligne;
  var Datas = fichier.getRange(RefCellule).getValues();
  var Agenda = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789@group.calendar.google.com').createAllDayEvent(Datas[0][0], new Date(Datas[0][1]),new Date(Datas[0][2]));
}
```

I notice that my script runs 2 times when the form is completed.
So, I have 2 identical events in the agenda.
This is not (necessarily) the case when testing the script from the editor (not always anyway).
An idea ? Why is this script run 2 times?
Thank you for your clarifications

Comment: What Triggers do you have associated with this?  Can you share the file?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if multiple users have the same submit trigger set up on the Google Form? If yes, then you should delete the trigger from other accounts and leave only one.

Comment: Even without the trigger, the code in the script editor runs 2 times (sometimes 3 times). This is not related to the form. Thanks